# I don’t know why blender 2.8 keeps crashing when I do simple task

Tags: particles, force-fields

So I started doing this project, creating a tornado with particles and force fields and when I go to press play, or move the playhead it repeatedly crashes, and can’t get past this point.

I don’t know if it’s because I don’t have the right settings to optimize my PC or what. I need someone who knows about computers to lend a helping hand.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Probably the task's too demanding for your hardware. E.g. too many particles.